# How to hide particular section in UITableViewController on change of UISwitch in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

My UITableView have 3 sections 
1)Show UISwitch to the user to ask whether you want to show image or not
2)Show two text fields
3)Show ImageView to display image

and i want to hide 3rd section on change of UISwitch.
both 3 sections are static.
and the action of uiswitch is given below

```
 @IBAction func stateChanged(switchState: UISwitch, tableView: UITableView )
{
    if switchState.on {
        showImageLB.text = "Yes"
        println( "The Switch is On")
    } else {
        showImageLB.text = "No"
        println("The Switch is Off")
    }
}
```

Please help me to get the solution.
Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Each time the UISwitch is flipped, you need to add a new row to your section that has ImageView.

To add more rows and to hide a section, all you need to do is to call `reloadData` on your tableView. 
Once you call this `reloadData`, 2 of your following functions will be called again.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

All you have to do now, is that once your switch if flipped, save a boolean and return different values in your functions.

For example.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
if(switchState.on)
{
 return 2; // now you are hiding your last section. 
}
else
{
return 3; // now you are showing all 3 sections when switch is off.
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks iosDev82 ..
Should i get some reference code for this or any reference link to do this because i am beginner in swift and ios.